# How to set global data on Vue on runtime?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm working with a Vue application that needs to get data from jsp on runtime, so I cannot create any kind of .env files. So I'm trying to set data to Vue and it needs to be accessible from whole application (components, mixins, ts modules etc). I think Vue prototype is a good alternative and it's working to Vue application but I cannot get them on ts modules.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'

class VueInstance {
  data: any

  constructor () {
    this.data = {}
  }

  public setData(key: string, data: any) {
    this.data[key] = data
    return this
  }

  public init() {
    Vue.prototype.$GLOBAL_DATA = this.data

    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount('app')
  }
}

export default function createVueInstance() {
  return new VueInstance()
}
```

That is my JSP file where I start the application and pass some data:

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<%
    String javaVar = "javaVar";
%>

<aui:script require="<%= mainRequire %>">
    main
    .default('app')
    .setData('foo', 'foo')
    .setData('bar', 'bar')
    .setData('javaVar', '<%= javaVar %>')
    .init()
</aui:script>
```

That is an example of ts module that I need to get my global data:

```js
const apiUrl = $GLOBAL_DATA // comming from prototype or something else.

export default {
   getData() {
      return axios.get(`${apiUrl}/foo`)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this.

I would state the problem as follows: The backend knows about things (like the api baseUrl) and the frontend (javascript application) needs to know about this.

Method 1: Providing data via the window object.

```
// backend
<div id="app"></div>

<script>
// backendvariable could be a string
// we could even JSON-encode the data

window.APP_CONFIG = <%= backendVariable %>

// alternatively:
window.APP_CONFIG = {
    API_URL: <%= apiUrl %>,
    SOME_CONSTANT: <%= someConstant %>,
    ...
}
</script>
```

```
// somewhere in our frontend
const apiUrl = window.APP_CONFIG.API_URL;
```

Method 2: Supplying data via the Vue instance
When your javascript bundle only contains the defined components but leaves the mounting of Vue up to your backend.

```
// backend
<div id="app"></div>

<script>
new Vue({ 
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      API_URL: <%= backendVariable %>
   }
});
</script>
```

now our server variable will be available to all Vue components via this.$root.API_URL (or $root.API_URL inside Vue templates). It wont be available outside the Vue application.

Method 3: Supplying data via the mounting point

```
// backend
<div id="app" 
   data-api-url="<%= backendVariable %>" 
   config='<%= jsonEncodedData %>' 
></div>
```

When you try using to add jsonEncodedData you should write single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
// in your frontend 
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   mounted() { 
       // This is how we access the externally provided data
       var API_URL = this.$el.getAttribute('data-api-url');

       // it's up to you to put this value accessible to 
       // all the consumers. 

       // You are not limited to scalar values:
       try { 
          var CONFIG = JSON.parse(this.$el.getAttribute('config') || '{}');
       } catch (e) {
           console.error("Invalid json supplied to app: ", e);
           var CONFIG = { }; // default config
       }
   }
});
```

It's also possible to JSON.parse()

Method 4: Supplying data via the mounting point template.
We have a javascript bundle that mounts the Vue app to #app.

```
// backend
// In this case our mounting point also includes a bare template
<div id="app">
   <app v-bind:config='<%= jsonEncodedData %>'></app>
   // or: 
   <app v-bind:config='{"api_url": "value"}'></app>
</div>
```

```
import App from './app.vue';
// frontend main
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: { App }
});
```

```
// app.vue will receive our json encoded backend-data
// because we did v-bind:config Vue will automatically json-parse the data
// for us. 
<script>
export default { 
    props: ['config']
}
</script>
```

Again you are free to make this config data available to the rest of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Joshua, it was very useful. I think using window object is the easiest option for me in that case and workred to solve my problem. I'm also trying using mixins, so I have access to vue instance and get the property object. So, in my VueInstance class, I get the data I passed by Java on main.default().setData() and I exposed and shared that data using mixins. That is not the best option because it changes the components structure but is also a good alternative.

Comment: Hi Renan, thank you for your kind reply. As I understand it mixins are a good mechanism for sharing behavior between components. I'm inclined to think they do add some weight to the initialization phase of components, which would make them less favorable to use as a way to share data across components. But I haven't got any hard evidence for these assumptions.